# Сортировка чисел ORDER BY

Tags: php, сортировка

Нужна сортировка чисел по убыванию или возрастанию не важно, которые выводятся из БД. Я применил вот такой код

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT power FROM teplo_db WHERE type_tovar='Электрические' AND visible='1' ORDER BY power ASC",$link);
```

Но выводимые числа сортируются по первому числу т.е получается: 11, 1, 27, 2, 35, 3 и.т.д "единичные" числа оказываются в середине двухзначных. Как это победить?

Answer (score 0):

Пока писал вопрос, на этом форуме нашел ответ :)
Оказалось все просто: к сортируемым строкам нужно прибавить 1 
Пример кода:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT power FROM teplo_db WHERE type_tovar='Электрические' AND visible='1' ORDER BY power+1 ASC",$link);
```

Comment: *к сортируемым строкам нужно прибавить 1* Лучше ноль.